# Tcl: fastest way to check for existence of array element

Tags: tcl

What is the fastest way in Tcl to test whether an element of an array exists?

1. Currently I use `info exists ::myArray($myKey)`, is that efficient?
2. I could use `llength [array names ::myArray -exact $myKey]`, would that be faster?

These are also the possibilities listed in the Tcl book by Nadkarni. Any other ideas which are more efficient?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd test `array names ::myArray -exact $myKey` against empty list. The `llength` feels like overkill.

Comment: @Andreas: better to use `expr {[array names ::myArray -exact $myKey] != {}}` or `expr {[array names ::myArray -exact $myKey] ne ""}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a specific element of an array, *by far* the fastest way to check is to use `info exists ::myArray($myKey)`; it compiles to its own bytecode opcode (`existArrayStk`) that is implemented efficiently — possibly one hash table lookup to find the array implementation (there are caches that might apply), and one hash table lookup to get the element, if any. (It's sometimes faster to not qualify the array name; that depends on context though.)

The `array names` command is always going to be slower; if nothing else, it isn't bytecoded. While in this case it might be able to avoid a linear scan of the array, it's still definitely got to do list construction and so on. There's simply more costs on that code path, and likely to always be so.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I will stick to `info exists`.